# How to improve/understand typechecking performance in Agda?

Tags: agda, performance

I've recently been trying to do some basic formalization of category theory in Agda. As part of this I need to prove a bunch of basic properties around products/monoidal categories. A bunch of these involve many steps that basically boil down to associate the tree of morphisms correctly, apply one identity, and repeat 3-5 times.

I was finding that these were slow and so tried to build some tooling that better provided Agda annotations around what the intermediate states were (also helps me read the proofs).

Example before:

```hs
sub1-no-zip : nt-inv ⋆ ×⟨ π₁ ⋆ π₂ , π₂ ⟩ ⋆ π₁ == π₂ ⋆ π₁
sub1-no-zip =
  (C.⋆-assocⁱ >=>
   C.⋆-right π₁-reduce >=>
   sym C.⋆-assocⁱ >=>
   C.⋆-left π₁-reduce >=>
   π₂-reduce)
```

Example after:

```hs
sub1-zip : nt-inv ⋆ ×⟨ π₁ ⋆ π₂ , π₂ ⟩ ⋆ π₁ == π₂ ⋆ π₁
sub1-zip =
  (begin
   [ []           , nt-inv ⋆ ×⟨ π₁ ⋆ π₂ , π₂ ⟩ ⋆ π₁   ,       [] ]=< right⇒ >
   [ []           , nt-inv ⋆ ×⟨ π₁ ⋆ π₂ , π₂ ⟩        , π₁ :: [] ]=< shift⇐ >
   [ [] :: nt-inv , ×⟨ π₁ ⋆ π₂ , π₂ ⟩ ⋆ π₁            ,       [] ]=< z-cong π₁-reduce >
   [ [] :: nt-inv , π₁ ⋆ π₂                           ,       [] ]=< shift⇒ >
   [ []           , nt-inv ⋆ π₁                       , π₂ :: [] ]=< z-cong π₁-reduce >
   [ []           , ×⟨ π₁ , π₂ ⋆ π₁ ⟩                 , π₂ :: [] ]=< right⇐ >
   [ []           , ×⟨ π₁ , π₂ ⋆ π₁ ⟩ ⋆ π₂            ,       [] ]=< z-cong π₂-reduce >
   [ []           , π₂ ⋆ π₁                           ,       [] ]end)
```

Full code: https://github.com/endobson/agda/blob/slow-test/category/cartesian-test.agda

The issue is that seems like it is even slower, and intermediate results show that while my extra framework adds some slowness, it is the annotations of the end points between each step that are slowing it. So it seems like Agda is faster at inferring than checking in this case.

Performance numbers:

```
Checking category.cartesian-test (/Users/endobson/proj/agda/category/cartesian-test.agda).
Total                                        751ms
Miscellaneous                                610ms
category.cartesian-test._._.sub1-zip          55ms
category.cartesian-test._._.sub1-zip-no-mor   37ms
category.cartesian-test._._.sub1-zip-no-anno  28ms
category.cartesian-test._._.sub1-no-zip       19ms
```

The performance of Agda's type checker/inference/elaboration is a black box to me. Is there a mental model I should approach it with? Are there options I can pass to agda so that I can get insight into a cost model other than milliseconds.

Comment: Is your equational reasoning syntax defined as in https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.Reasoning.Base.Single.html, noting the comment in the middle of the file? Aside from that, my guess at a solution would be to write a reflection-based solver for Cartesian categories, comparable to [this category solver](https://github.com/agda/agda-categories/blob/master/src/Categories/Tactic/Category.agda). The theory is that computations happen on the (very simple) reflected syntax, rather than the full Agda syntax.